# Big-endian vs. little-endian machines

Tags: endianness

I understand what the difference between the two are. Looking at [the entry in Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) it seems like litte-endian format is gaining ground and this is not as much of an issue as it used to be.

HP-UX on Itanium is the only newer processor that is using big-endian format. Most others are using little-endian, which is an indication that industry is standardizing on this. Is this true? Am I missing something? Do any of these differences exist for mobile OS like iOS and Android?

Comment: I always though only Intel and those copying Intelwere using little-endian. Perhaps Intel won the religious war. Just noticed bi-endian in your link, I would guess that's the final answer.

Comment: @YavorShahpasov, That is not true. ARM cores can be configured either way and most of them seem to be little.

Comment: The statement that itanium is only big-endian is wrong. it supports little endian as well as big endian

Answer (score 5):

The ARM architecture runs both little & big endianess, but the Android, iOS 6, and Windows Phone platforms run little endian. 95% of modern desktop computers are little-endian.

Comment: Any sources to back up your claims?

Comment: Do you have any citations or links to back this up? Fleshing your answer out a bit with facts, etc. tends to give a better impression, as "95%" looks a little arbitrary.

Comment: All x86 desktops (which is nearly all desktops with the demise of the PowerPC-based Macs several years ago) are little-endian. It's probably actually a lot more than 95% nowadays. PowerPC was the only non-x86 architecture that has been popular for desktop computers in the last 20 years and Apple finally abandoned it in favor of x86. Sparc, Alpha, and Itanium did exist, but they were all very rare in the desktop market.

Comment: You mention desktops only here, but the question is entirely valid for servers, mainframes and more exotic machines, that can still be found today in data centers, and might not be that modern.